# TextJustify quality issue

Tags: android, justify

I've two problems.

1. If you have a look on the "amet" of the image you see a very strange formatting. Would it be possible to disable the space beetween characters and only add spaces between words?
2. The text quality is very bad. The characters looks very thin and you can see the pixels. Changing the typeface wouldn't change this

I use the following Library:

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

I use this code:

```
DocumentView documentView = new DocumentView(context, DocumentView.FORMATTED_TEXT);
documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);
documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
documentView.getDocumentLayoutParams().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);
documentView.setCacheConfig(DocumentView.CacheConfig.NO_CACHE);
documentView.setText(part);
```

[image: test]

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. It will be addressed in the next couple days.

Answer (score 0):

As you use Formatted_TEXT use \n\r for going to next line or `&#13;&#10`;
at the end of your document use `&#13&#10;` like this:

> It's the ASCII character LF, Line Feed.`&#13&#10;`
>   Some systems (e.g. Windows) use the combination CR+LF, 
> , for
>   line break, some systems (e.g. Linux) use only LF as line break, some
>   systems (e.g. Macintosh) use only CR as line break.`&#13&#10;`